# Lost Header values in Camel route while testing using RouteReifer.adviceWith(..)

Tags: apache-camel

Using camel 3.4.4, I've a route that calls a cxf endpoint with `.to(getCxfEndpoint())` and I've a header that's set earlier in the route like `process(exchange -> exchange.getIn().setHeader("myKey", "myValue")`:

```
from(someEndpoint)
.process(exchange -> exchange.getIn().setHeader("myKey", "myValue")
.to(getCxfEndpoint())
.process(exchange -> String value = exchange.getIn().getHeader("myKey");
```

I'm trying to unit test this using the following:

```
RouteReifer.adviceWith(routeDefinition, mcc, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {

    @Override
    public void configure() {
      weaveByString("To[http://myurl.com/xxx").replace()
       process(exchange -> {
         log.debug("Assume external call is made and I can see the headers in exchange here");
       });
    
    }
    });
```

But in the route, when I try to get the header `exchange.getIn().getHeader("myKey")`, it's null. This only happens in test - it actually works when you run the real route. I'm unable to figure out why the header is lost after I mock the call using `weaveByString`. Also the headers are still present in the lambda in `process` above.

Thanks in advance.